# How does the hashtable work

Tags: java, hashtable

I have something like this:

```
private void convertLevel(String courseLevel)
{
    //This allows you to define your list with string keys instead of
    //using a bunch of ifs.
    Hashtable<String, Character> CourseLevels = new Hashtable<String, Character>();
    {
        CourseLevels.put("IB", '7');

        CourseLevels.put("Academic", '1');

        CourseLevels.put("Applied", '1');

        CourseLevels.put("ELL", '9');

        CourseLevels.put("Special Education", '8');
    };
    //Determine if the courseLevel exists in our list.
    if (CourseLevels.contains(courseLevel))
    {
        //Assuming level is defined as a char and not a string
        //Yes it does, use it.
        level = CourseLevels.get(courseLevel); // gives me an error saying incompatible types
    }
    else
    {
        //if not use the default.    
        level = DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me why this is happening

level is a string, and is defined in the other parts of the class

Comment: Where is `level` defined?

Comment: Next time please post also your error message

Answer (score 2):

hashtable's `contains(Object value)` test the value, not key! so basically, it is same as `containsValue()`. You may want to use  `containsKey()` method.

Comment: that still doesnt solve the problem

Comment: you added in your question: `level is a string, and is defined in the other parts of the class`, you defined the hashtable: `Hashtable<String, Character>`, so the `get(String key)`  will return a `Character`, but you assign it to a String (level)...bang! @user3709657

Comment: @user3709657 I don't know the requirement, but you need either make `level` as `Character` or make the hashtable `<String, String>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will try to explain what I know.
An Hashtable is a table with a structure like
    key => value

Where key is like the "name" of every element of the table and value is its value
Let's take some code as example

```
Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
table.put("key here", "value here");
table.put("hash", "table");
```

This table will look like this

```
"key here" => "value here"
"hash" => "table"
```

Now we can get the values stored in the table by calling the get method

```
String value = table.get("key here"); //will return "value here"
String value2 = table.get("hash"); //will return "table"
```

Hashtables are like php associative arrays.
Besides searching a value in an Hashtable is very fast because its search is made by hashing algorithms and not by comparate every single item of the table